# PHP array manipulation, switch values with specific keys - pattern?

Tags: php, arrays

I've got array data which outputs as:

```
'TextField3283' => string 'A'
'TextField3287' => string 'B'
'TextField3288' => string 'C'
'Custom_TextField3283' => string 'customfield_10202'
'Custom_TextField3287' => string 'customfield_10216'
'Custom_TextField3288' => string 'customfield_10212'
```

What I need to do is shuffle the key and values to create the following output:

```
'customfield_10202' => 'A'
'customfield_10216' => 'B'
'customfield_10212' => 'C'
```

So the value of the last three entries become the keys of a new array, with the correct values. As you can see, the last three entries are the same as the first three but prefixed with Custom_

With this in mind, I've attempted to use:

```
$customfields = array();

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

    if (preg_match("/_TextField/", $key)) {
        array_push($customfields, array($value => $key));
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
'customfield_10202' => 'Custom_TextField3283'
'customfield_10216' => 'Custom_TextField3287'
'customfield_10212' => 'Custom_TextField3288'
```

But now I'm not sure the best way to lookup the values as keys in the first array and return their values...

I hope this makes sense

Comment: 1. Create 2 arrays: of text fields and custom text fields with numeric keys like `3283`. 2. merge them (after you have pre-processed separated arrays this step is trivial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close with your attempt. Provided your array stays as it is, all you need to do is this:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

    if (preg_match("/_TextField/", $key)) {
        list($unused, $findkey) = explode("_", $key);
        array_push($customfields, array($value => $array[$findkey]));
    }
}
```

Notice how we `explode()` on the `_`? That's because the key for the value is set as an array index.

[**Example**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#MG6RBLxw6)

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was after. Yeah I'd worked out the explode after posting, just not the rest. Thank you very much.